# Override previous line in stdout with \r

Tags: c, linux, printing

So usually when I want to print something on the previous line in the terminal I just do:

```
printf("\rprint a number %d", number);
fflush(stdout);
```

So for a program I'm writing I wanted to do just that and tried:

```
printf("\r%s - %s", buffer1, buffer2);
fflush(stdout);
```

Where

```
buffer1, buffer2 = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
```

This does however not work, it prints on a new line everytime. I'm assuming it has something to do with me using char* instead of char[100] or with the size of them?

Sample output (colors removed from code for simplicity):

[image: sample]

edit:
`buffer_1` gets populated in a different thread from stdin:

```
while (true) {
    system("/bin/stty raw");
    c = getchar();
    system("/bin/stty cooked");
    if (c == ' ') {
        return;
    }
    // check if input is not to long
    if (i == MAX_INPUT_LENGTH) {
        return;
    }
    // Get the latest added char and add to buffer
    t_a->input_buffer[i] = c;
    i += 1;
}
```

And `buffer_2` is assigned the output from `system(find)` command:

```
 FILE *fp = popen("find -name a ", "r");
 char temp_buf[1024];
 // Get output of find command
 int i = 0;
 while (fgets(temp_buf, sizeof(temp_buf), fp) != 0 && i < MAX_NUM_RESULTS) {
     strcpy(result_buffer[i], temp_buf);
     i += 1;
 }

pclose(fp);
```

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: What do you do with `buffer1` and `buffer2`? What is the contents of those buffers? Do perhaps `buffer2` contain a trailing newline?

Comment: Perhpas you obtained the input with `fgets` which retains the newline (if any) as part of the string.

Comment: Just added how the buffers get filled. I never entered a newline while testing, however it could be possible that it's included in the `find` output? @WeatherVane is there a simple way to print the string including newline characters to check this ?

Comment: The problem was exactly what you suggested, thanks for pointing me there!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was indeed that the output from `system(find)` contained a newline at the end of the result. I fixed this by not copying the last character:

```
 strncpy(result_buffer[i], temp_buf, strlen(temp_buf)-1);
```

Thanks to the comments for pointing me there!

Comment: Be wary of this method. It's better to copy what you are given and *then* remove any newline with the method given in comment by @user3121023 which is completely safe - whether or not a newline is there.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how much line feed you have, you can use `strspn` function in a loop to remove all `\n` occurrences:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void remove_line_feeds(char *sz)
{
    size_t len = strlen(sz);
    size_t pos;

    while ((pos = strspn(sz, "\n"))!= len)
    {
        sz[pos] = ' ';
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char sz[] = "text\nwith\nline\nfeed";

    printf("'%s'\n", sz);

    remove_line_feeds(sz);

    printf("'%s'\n", sz);
    return 0;
}
```